# include css and JavaScript file on node express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, visual-studio-code

I want to include my css file and javascript file in node-express, but I always got 404 not found: here my code:
 1. in server.js

```
var http = require('http');
var app = require('./app');
var express = require('express');
var apps = express();
var path = require('path');

apps.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
http.createServer(app.handleRequest).listen(8000);
```

then on app.js

```
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');

function renderHTML(path, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    fs.readFile(path, null, function(error, data) {
        if (error) {
            response.writeHead(404);
            response.write('File not found!');
        } else {
            response.write(data);

        }
        response.end();
    });
}
```

and My route still on app.js:

```
module.exports = {
    handleRequest: function(request, response) {
        var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
        switch (path) {
            case '/':
                renderHTML('./index.html', response);
                break;
            case '/login':
                renderHTML('./login.html', response);
                break;
            default:
                response.writeHead(404);
                response.write('Route not defined');
                response.end();
        }
    }
};
```

And this is my html:

```
  <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Test Doc</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" />
    </head>    
    <body>
        <p>Coba ku </p>
        <div id="container" style="height: 500px"></div>
    </body>  
    </html>
```

I use vs-code to built this.

Comment: What is the req url for css and js files? also make sure your css and js files are in a root folder of your project named `public`

Comment: Any updates? Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I got confused. You use express to process static files, but why are you create a native node server without express，express does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Change you `server.js`

```
var app = require('./app');
var express = require('express');
var apps = express();
var path = require('path');

apps.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
apps.use(app.handleRequest);
apps.listen(8000);
```

Learn the official doc [app.listen()](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.listen) to understand how it should look.

---

There is no need to create a function like `renderHTML` to serve out HTML.

```
// Instead of this:
renderHTML('./index.html', response);

// Just use that:
response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public', 'index.html'));
// or (the same):
response.sendFile('index.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, '../public') });
```

You can find more information here [res.sendFile()](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile).

---

And I have to say, that there is a better way to implement the routing which you've implemented via `switch` in the `app.handleRequest()` function. [Routing](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)